# How to count the frequency of letter for each line

Tags: python

I want to count the frequency of the letters of the alphabet from a txt file. No distinguish between uppercase and lowercase letters, so it doens't matter if it's a "b" or "B".

I thought it was possible to set a alphabet list in def count_letters()
     like: alphabet = "abc...xyz"
and then check each line for the frequency of the letters.

I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import string

def show_result():
    analyze_file(filename.get())

def analyze_file(filename):
    try:
        infile = open(filename, "r")
        # ... create a list counts ...
        # ... for each line call count_letters ...
        infile.close()

    # show histogram
    histogram(counts)
     except IOError:
    tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Analyze File", 
                                "File " + filename + " does not exist")

  # count each letter in the string 
def count_letters(line, counts): 
    #code...
     pass

def open_file():
     filenameforReading = askopenfilename()
     filename.set(filenameforReading)
...
```

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Seeing you asked several questions but haven't yet accepted a single answer, you may also benefit of reading the [tour].

Comment: ok sorry then i won't ask anymore

Comment: @mrobertini1239 The intention of my comment was not to discourage you from asking questions in the future, but to familiarize yourself with how to formulate an on-topic question for this site. As mentioned by Rad Lexus in their comment, there is nothing stopping you from editing your question further to add the necessary information to have a well received question here.

Comment: How can i accept an answer. Can you explain it?

Comment: @mrobertini1239 When someone posts an answer, there is a grey "check mark" next to their answer. Clicking that check mark will turn it "green", which indicates you have accepted that answer. Important to note that you can only accept one answer per question. So ensure you are selecting the one that in fact helped solve your problem. I would advise revising all your previous questions and accepting the answers that did in fact help you

Comment: @idjaw i've edited my post :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can understand, `collections.Counter` is what you're after.

```
from collections import Counter

def count_letters(line): 
    return Counter(line.lower())
```

Assuming `line` is a string, this will convert all of the letters to lower case and return a dictionary-like object with the counts of all letters. 
eg:

```
count_letters('Bananas are berries!')
```

will produce

```
Counter({
    'a': 4, 
    'e': 3, 
    'r': 3, 
    ' ': 2, 
    'b': 2, 
    'n': 2, 
    's': 2,  
    'i': 1, 
    '!': 1
})
```